# Laravel check if date is between 2 dates.

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I want to check if today's date is between to dates dat are stored in the
database. Right now I do this with laravel eloquent:

```
 return Set::where('type', $type)
            ->where('active_from', '<=', date("Y-m-d"))
            ->where('active_until', '>=', date("Y-m-d"))
            ->first();
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Does it return the results you expect?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming both `active_from` and `active_until` contains only dates it's correct, but if they contain dates with times you should probably use `whereDate` instead of `where` like so:

```
return Set::where('type', $type)
            ->whereDate('active_from', '<=', date("Y-m-d"))
            ->whereDate('active_until', '>=', date("Y-m-d"))
            ->first();
```

Also, looking at the code I'm pretty sure you should use operators the other way: `active_from` should be `>=` and `active_until` should be `<=`

Comment: should this work if the example active_from and active_until is set as varchar in the database?